# Using image from sprite in list item after its' content

Tags: css, html-lists, css-sprites

I have the following html for ul:

```
<div id="articlesideitems">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span style="">List item content 1</span><span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>List item content 2</span><span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>List item long long long long long long content</span><span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>List item long long long long long long content</span><span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>                                                                                                          
  </ul>
<div id="articlesideitems">
```

and css:

```
div#articlesideitems ul li span {
   display: inline-block;
}

div#articlesideitems ul li span:last-child {
   background: url('images/sprite.png') no-repeat -87px -13px;
   width: 9px;
   height: 16px;
   margin-left: 10px;
}
```

and the output is similar to:

[image]

As you see, when text has more than one line, the double arrow is not at the end of text, but on a new line. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: You could achieve this with a lot less mark up (no spans) and no need for an external image by using a pseudo element. Would that be an option for you?

Comment: Yes, it can be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `display: inline-block` only to `span:last-child`

```
div#articlesideitems ul li span:last-child {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpKoNg

---

Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option for you that reduces the amount of markup required by removing all the `<span>`s and also removes the need for an external image by using the `::after` pseudo element to insert the double angle quotation mark (`\bb`), preceded a non-breaking space (`\a0`). It won't look *exactly* the same as it does in your sprite so you'll need to decide if that's an acceptable sacrifice.

[More information on pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

Resize your browser window to see how the lines break.

```css
body{margin:0;}
#articlesideitems ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    width:50%;
}
#articlesideitems li{
    border-bottom:1px solid #009;
}
#articlesideitems a{
    color:#009;
    display:block;
    font-family:verdana;
    padding:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#articlesideitems a::after{
    content:"\a0\bb";
}
```

```html
<div id="articlesideitems">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">List item content 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List item content 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List item long long long long long long content</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List item long long long long long long content</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```